# Wifi is hard locked

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I just got a new laptop and installed Ubuntu on it. Wi-fi worked fine on Windows 8, but now it says that it's disabled by a hardware switch. `rfkill unblock all` did nothing. Many people have suggested installing something, but there's no ethernet port. Tried using a USB dongle, that's blocked too.

Do I have to go spend $25 on an ethernet to USB adapter I'll only use once, or is there another way?

Here's the output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
7: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Make and Model of laptop?

Comment: "hard lock" actually means what it says: you have a switch on your machine itself, in the bios or on your keyboard to lock wifi.

Comment: @Mitch Lenovo Yoga 2 11.6".

Comment: @Rinzwind There's no switch. There is a keyboard key that soft blocks it, and it's off. And I enabled it in the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

This has been [fixed](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-utopic.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c?id=85093f79f586176f8bbf90e56e22a3dfa526e334) for Yoga in kernel 3.16.

For Ubuntu 14.04 just upgrade your kernel to 3.16 by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

or to 3.19 by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: That is awesome. Have been trying to get wifi started since three days.

Comment: Can there be a reason why the wifi may again stop working after an hour.

Comment: @RED Do you have exactly same wireless adapter? If not, ask another question. This answer does not relate to all adapters.

Comment: Not the same but upgrading the kernel again worked.

Answer (score 0):

"hard lock" actually means what it says: you have a switch on your machine itself, in the bios or on your keyboard to lock wifi.

Look around your laptop.

Comment: There is no hard switch in that model. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After trying many different suggestions, I found out that my wifi have been turned off by the "Radio on/off" key on my keyboard (usually having an antenna or radio tower symbol on it; on Dell laptop, Fn+F2 key-combination).
**I see that *"MUY Belgium*" has suggested that, too; I would up-vote his answer, if I had enough reputation score.**

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer.

Comment: You are right. Now, I noticed that in the comments to the first answer (just for the records: my ubuntu version is 18.04).